# group clock in and clock out attendance query

Tags: sql, mysql, grouping

I have Attendance table:

| EmpId | DateEntry | AttType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E-0001 | 2024-01-01 08:00:02 | IN |
| E-0001 | 2024-01-01 17:01:00 | OUT |
| E-0002 | 2024-01-01 07:59:02 | IN |
| E-0002 | 2024-01-01 17:00:07 | OUT |

How to query this table into:

| DateEntry | EmpID | ClockIn | ClockOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | E-0001 | 08:00:02 | 17:01:00 |
| 2024-01-01 | E-0002 | 07:59:02 | 17:00:07 |

where the ClockIn/ClockOut is based on AttType (when 'IN' then ClockIn, when 'OUT' then ClockOut)

I tried this query :

```
SELECT EmpID,
       DateEntry,
       CASE
           WHEN AttType = 'IN' THEN DateEntry
           ELSE NULL
       END AS ClockIn,
       CASE
           WHEN AttType = 'OUT' THEN DateEntry
           ELSE NULL
       END AS ClockOut
FROM Attendance
GROUP BY EmpID,
         DateEntry;
```

but the results was:

| DateEntry | EmpID | ClockIn | ClockOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | E-0001 | 08:00:02 |  |
| 2024-01-01 | E-0001 |  | 17:01:00 |
| 2024-01-01 | E-0002 | 07:59:02 |  |
| 2024-01-01 | E-0002 |  | 17:00:07 |

how to get the correct result? anyone can help me? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation based on the date part using the aggregate function `MAX()` :

```
SELECT DATE(DateEntry) AS DateEntry,
       EmpID,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN AttType = 'IN' THEN TIME(DateEntry)
           ELSE NULL
       END) AS ClockIn,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN AttType = 'OUT' THEN TIME(DateEntry)
           ELSE NULL
       END) AS ClockOut
FROM Attendance
GROUP BY EmpID,
         DATE(DateEntry);
```

Results :

```
DateEntry   EmpID   ClockIn     ClockOut
2024-01-01  E-0001  08:00:02    17:01:00
2024-01-01  E-0002  07:59:02    17:00:07
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/g1WB3pzH)

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(in.DateEntry,'%y-%m-%d'), in.EmpID,
  TIME(in.DateEntry) AS ClockIn,
  TIME(out.DateEntry) AS ClockOut
FROM Attendance AS in
LEFT JOIN Attendance as out ON in.EmpID = out.EmpID AND out.AttType ='OUT'
WHERE in.AttType = 'IN';
```